# Loading the next scene in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

Im new in unity/scripting.Basicly what Im trying to do is make the next level (on build settings) load on collision.I created an empty object and attached a box collider to it.It loads the SPECIFIED scenes correctly but I wanna make it so it only loads the next scene,so I don't have to create 100+scripts.

This is what I've been working with :

```
#pragma strict

function OnCollisionEnter(Collision : Collision)
{
if(Collision.collider.tag == "Player")
{
    Application.LoadLevel("Easy17");
}

}
```

And this is my progress so far:

```
#pragma strict

public var lvl = Application.LoadLevel; 

function OnCollisionEnter(Collision : Collision)
{
if(Collision.collider.tag == "Player")
{
    Application.LoadLevel(lvl + 1);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy way. Since you have already set up your build settings accordingly, you can just do the following:

```
Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel + 1);
```

,since `Application.loadedLevel` returns the level actually loaded.

Pay attention to handle the special case regarding the final level!

**UPDATE**: I just noticed that your logic is the same. But it seems that you wrote `LoadLevel` instead than `LoadedLevel`, in `lvl` assignment (`LoadLevel()` is the function, `LoadedLevel` is the attribute!).